# Can I create a "Mega Menu" by altering the CSS alone?

Tags: magento2, category, layout

I wanna create a simple mega menu that removes the annoying hover ul's and have a full width container with all the links of each category visible. 
Can I do this with just the CSS or will there be other factors I'll need to take into consideration.

I've found Magento2 has a pretty strict structure and changing one element can have a roll on effect on others. So I thought I'd ask first. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, @Azul_Falcone have you figured it out to convert the default menu to Megamenu. in Magento 2

Comment: No, sorry. We ended up using a Mega Menu.

Comment: Paid or free Extension

Comment: I actually found a free one, but I can't remember the name of it, sorry. It wasnt available via Connect, so Google will probably be the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do megamenu only using alter css. you have to do changes strucutre for menu from **`vendor\module_theme\Block\Html\Topmenu.php`** file.

Megamenu for magento 2, you have to add/remove div for your requirements so its better to override **`Topmenu.php`** file and do chagnes as per your requirements of megamenu. Css is needed to do megamenu but only css cant help you.

Thanks.